# How does Contiki OS process external interrupts?

Tags: process, operating-system, interrupt, avr-gcc, contiki

It is possible to wake sensor nodes on external interrupts that are generated by peripheral sensors. The following explains how Contiki OS handles external interrupts. In case of the `ATmega128RFA1` the external interrupts `INT0` to `INT4` are able to wake the MCU even from **deep sleep**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an overview over processes and interupts in contiki is here:

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Processes

http://de.slideshare.net/DingxinXu/contiki-introduction-iifrom-what-to-how

http://senstools.gforge.inria.fr/doku.php?id=os:contiki

contiki utilizes the ISR vectors of the MCU

this example is for **ATmega128RFA1**. the external interrupt is INT0 on PD0 (pin 25)

in the ISR the only action is to **poll an associated contiki process**. Internally this sends a **poll request** to the process. The process catches the **poll request** and then executes the calculations associated with the external interrupt.  This proceeding prevents long lasting calculations in the ISR.

**ISR :**

```
ISR(INT0_vect)
{            

  process_poll(&extern_interupt_process);
  PRINTF("interrupt was triggered on INT0... \n");  

}
```

to enable the external interupts on INT0:

`EIMSK =  0xb00000000; //disable interrupts before changing EICRA
 EICRA |= 0xb00000011; //EICRA 0000|0011 rising edge triggers interrupt int0
 EIMSK |= 0xb00000001; // enable INT0` (datasheet p. 219 ff)

**process :**

```
PROCESS(extern_interupt_process, "external_interrupt_process");

PROCESS_THREAD(extern_interupt_process, ev, data)
{


  PROCESS_BEGIN();


  while(1) {

    PROCESS_YIELD_UNTIL(ev == PROCESS_EVENT_POLL);

    // process data here 

           }


  PROCESS_END();

}
```

use autostart_process() to start the extern_interrupt_process or start it manually in contiki-main.c

if the sensor has an **open collector** output activate the internal pull-up resistor and set the interrupt control register to trigger an interrupt on low-level (see this: [wiring a sensor with open collector output](https://books.google.de/books?id=HsTxON1L6D4C&pg=PT106&lpg=PT106&dq=open%20collector%20sensor%20avr%20pull%20up&source=bl&ots=JuQRsurFmU&sig=TXObFkfMDDBzeLvVjXI1XuGKlQI&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=open%20collector%20sensor%20avr%20pull%20up&f=false))

```
DDRD  &= 0xb00000000;   // PD0 as input
PORTD |= 0xb00000001;  // enable internal pull-up on PD0
EIMSK &= 0xb00000000; //disable interrupts before changing EICRA
EICRA &= 0xb00000000; //EICRA 0000|0000 low-level triggers interrupt on int0
EIMSK |= 0xb00000001; // enable INT0` (datasheet p. 219 ff)
```

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector)

Comment: On some platforms you also need to clear some status register bits to avoid going back to sleep mode after the interrupt handler is executed.